# Using channels and netem takes too long

Tags: java, linux, channel

I have a program that uses channels instead of sockets. I wanted to do some testing so I used `netem` to simulate packet loss. But the sending of NACKs takes too long.

e.g. With 0.5% packet loss and netem it needs 30 secs, but programmaticaly when I tell it to skip 0.5% of the packets it only takes about 1 sec.

Does netem add delay to the packet loss? Or does it affect channels especially?

Comment: How could it possibly know about the channels? What NACKs? What are you talking about?

Comment: tc and netem can produce unpredictable results if not configured correctly and carefully.  For detailed explanation see Anders Moe's thesis, "Implementing Rate Control in Netem" at http://home.ifi.uio.no/paalh/students/AndersMoe.pdf